# I have a Centos server... where can I find where the SMTP details for the email server?

Tags: email, apache-http-server, centos, smtp

Where can I find the SMTP details for each domain name I have? Tried several ways on my own as well and nothing so far!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That depends. First take a look at your domains' MX records. If they say your mail is already managed by your webhost (or your domain registrar), then ask the webhost (or registrar).

On the other hand, if you have no such service, and/or if you want to host everything yourself... then it's up to you to set up *your own* SMTP daemon as well (postfix, opensmtpd, exim4 are popular), and you're the one who *writes* the "SMTP details" instead of having to obtain them from someone else.

*(That said, hosting outgoing SMTP yourself can be a bit of a pain when it comes to battling false positives in other peoples' spam filters...)*

Comment: Oh really? Urgh ok! Basically

Comment: because Roundcube is already on there does that defo mean I have to still create my own SMTP details to run through Mail for example? Sorry for all the questions! Only got this server a couple of months ago!

Comment: If Roundcube is already there, check what configuration it uses. If it is configured to speak SMTP, just copy the same information to Mail.app or whatever. Though if it uses the server's _own_ mail daemon (localhost), there's a chance that the mail daemon is only configured to accept messages within the server and not from outside.